# Escape new line in jil file

Tags: autosys, jil

How could I escape new line in autosys jil file?

```
delete_job: <job name>
insert_job: <job name> job_type: c
command: <sh file>
machine: <host>
owner: <owner>
permission: gx,mx
condition: s(A, 06.00)
    & s(B, 06.00)
std_out_file: <job name>.out
std_err_file: <job name>.err
alarm_if_fail: 0
```

Previous gives me error:

```
CAUAJM_E_50254 Unexpected line for <job name>: &
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here by splitting the condition over two lines?

Comment: readability of huge codition